# Lucee 5.3: wrong locales

Tags: java, locale, lucee

I have a strange problem on my local development machine (not on test or production) and I need some help:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20 LTS
Java: openjdk 11.0.9 (Ubuntu) 64bit
Lucee: 5.3.7.47 (latest stable)
```

Code (cfscript):

```
content="1600.00";
result = "1.600,00";
formatMask="_,___.__";
locale="German (Austria)";
setLocale(locale);
formatedString = LSNumberFormat(content, formatMask, locale);
writeDump(locale);
writeDump(formatedString);
writeDump(result == formatedString);
writeDump(server.lucee.version);
```

Expected Result: https://trycf.com/gist/d418ce24140110378ee1e3387964a6aa/lucee5?theme=monokai

```
string  German (Austria)
string  1.600,00
boolean true
string  5.3.7.44
```

Actual Result:

```
string  German (Austria)
string  1 600,00
boolean false
string  5.3.7.47
```

Same issue with Locale "German (Switzerland)".

I already tried Lucee 5.2 and I have the same result local. I already spend hours with this problem and I have no more ideas. Thank you very much.